# What is the right Regular Expression for my validation?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I created a RegEx-based validation with SO's help and passed it off to my coworker explaining the reasons why it is needed (Referring to it as a Whitelist). The coworker then proceeded to change my code (insisting upon what they called a Blacklist) and modified the RegEx. The code corresponding to each approach is listed below. The validation should ensure that only a hyphen, numbers, spaces and letters are allowed. I'd like to know

1. Which of the code fragments achieves that?
2. How can I break my co-worker's code?
3. Is a Blacklist just a Whitelist with the condition inverted?

My co-worker's Code:

```
objRegExp.Pattern= "[^-A-Za-z0-9'&(). ]"

if objRegExp.Test(strInput) then
    FoundSpecialChar= true
    exit function
end if

FoundSpecialChar= false
Set objRegExp = Nothing
```

My Code:

```
objRegExp.Pattern= "^[-A-Za-z0-9\s'&().]+"   

if objRegExp.Test(strInput) then
    FoundSpecialChar= false
    exit function
end if

FoundSpecialChar= true
Set objRegExp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colleague's approach lists the acceptable characters. If it finds even one character not in that list, it sets `FoundSpecialChar= true` which seems to be what you want. To test the difference between his code and yours, you could try to run both the code fragments with `strInput = "ABCD#EFGH"`.

Running your code once with `strInput = "A#"` and another time with `strInput = "#A"` should help as well.

BTW, `Set objRegExp = Nothing` should be included before `Exit Function` as well.

Comment: ok. thanks. that makes sense.

Comment: If that answers your question, please upvote it and accept it as the answer. I'd also be helpful for future readers of this item if you describe what you did/tested and what your resolution is.

Answer (score 0):

I am from testing background and I've experienced that Whitelist approach is good from application developer point of view and Blacklist approach is good to test the application. The reason being, as a dev a Whitelist gives you control over the exact input that a user is allowed to enter. On the other hand, as a tester I would use the Blacklist approach more because it will have infinite number of options to test.

Interesting discussion on SO --> [blacklisting vs whitelisting in form's input filtering and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559621/blacklisting-vs-whitelisting-in-forms-input-filtering-and-validation)

Comment: Since this is not an answer, would you consider deleting it and instead adding it as a comment? (Since you're adding useful information)

Comment: I think he is just asking which approach is better. Not sure if he is raising any specific coding problem there.