# How to prevent SQL injection in Mule Applications?

Tags: mule, sql-injection, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

Are there best practices how to avoid SQL injection in case of Mule Applications?

I guess the [general guide-lines "how to avoid SQL injection"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) would work here as well...

> Primary Defenses:
>
> ```
> Option 1: Use of Prepared Statements (with Parameterized Queries)
> Option 2: Use of Stored Procedures
> Option 3: White List Input Validation
> Option 4: Escaping All User Supplied Input
> ```
>
> Additional Defenses:
>
> ```
> Also: Enforcing Least Privilege
> Also: Performing White List Input Validation as a Secondary Defense
> ```

But is there any built-in support, that helps to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: Options 2 and 4 are but a hoax. You must go for #1 and #3. Note that nowhere a white list is an "additional" defense, it's a first line defense, should be used everywhere when #1 is inapplicable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [recent blog post](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/connectivity-dev/new-database-connector-mule-4/) (October 12 2017):

There’s a brand new [Mule 4 Anypoint Connector for Database (DB)](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/database-connector/) that can be userd to connect to different relational Database engines (MySQL database, Microsoft SQL Server database, PostgreSQL database, Oracle Database, and more).

*This new connector is only available in Mule 4.*

**Mule 4**

The select operation introduced by the connector allows to use a parametrized SQL query, like in the following XML snippet:

```
<set-variable variableName="table" value="PLANET"/>
<db:select config-ref="dbConfig">
 <db:sql>#["SELECT * FROM $(vars.table) WHERE name = :name"]</db:sql>
 <db:input-parameters>
   #[{'name' : payload}]
 </db:input-parameters>
</db:select>
```

Using this approach the query is *supposed* to become immune to SQL injection attacks.

This will force the Mule Runtime to use a prepared statement, which is only compiled once. Since it is precompiled; the parameters will be handled purely as data and they can't be used to change the meaning of the SQL-query. Since the query won't be recompiled; the passed parameters can't be used to alter the SQL query.

For the details see the following StackOverflow question:

[How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)

This helps to avoid some kinds of attacks, but *this solution won't make the system 100% immune to SQL-injection*.

For details see the following question on the secury StackExchange:

[Are prepared statements 100% safe against SQL injection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/are-prepared-statements-100-safe-against-sql-injection)

According to this; by using prepared statements with parameterized queries and [white list input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559621/blacklisting-vs-whitelisting-in-forms-input-filtering-and-validation) you can avoid some/most types of attacks, but don't think, that your system is 100% secure.

Next to prepared statements with parameterized queries and user input sanitization you also need to have other lines of defence in place.

**Mule 3.9**

In Mule 3.9 you can use parameterized-query.

This is implemented by the "[SimpleQueryTemplateParser](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.modules/mule-module-db/3.5.0/org/mule/module/db/internal/parser/SimpleQueryTemplateParser.java)" class in the runtime.

This is going to replace the MEL expressions in your query text with question marks, creating a [parametrized SQL statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Even if the SQL statement with the MEL expressions looks a bit suspicious, it won't be simply concatenated.

For exqample in the following case:

```
SELECT * from employee where name = #[flowVars.name]
```

The `#[flowVars.name]` part is going to be replaced with a question mark and it will be recognized as an SQL query parameter and the following query will be created:

```
SELECT * from employee where name = ?
```

The MEL expression will be recognized and evaluated. It will be added as a parameter.

See also the [official documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/database-connector#query-types).

As you can see; a major improvement in Mule 4 is that it is using named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can define custom policy using yaml which for example can include whitelist of approved characters and enforce as a Security policy on MuleSoft API Manager.

There are in build policies like json and xml protection which can be of use as well.

References:

[DZone: Creating Custom Policies in MuleSoft](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-policies-in-mulesoft)

[DZone: Cheatsheat - Addressing OWASP Top 10 Vulnarabilities in MuleSoft APIs](https://dzone.com/articles/cheatsheet-addressing-owasp-top-10-vulnerabilities)