# R regex match things other than known characters

Tags: r, regex

For a text field, I would like to expose those that contain invalid characters. The list of invalid characters is unknown; I only know the list of accepted ones. 
For example for French language, the accepted list is 
`A-z, 1-9, [punc::], space, àéèçè, hyphen, etc.`

The list of invalid charactersis unknown, yet I want anything unusual to resurface, for example, I would want

`This is an 2-piece à-la-carte dessert` to pass when

`'Ã this Øs an apple'` pumps up as an anomalie

The 'not contain' notion in R does not behave as I would like, for example

```
grep("[^(abc)]",c("abcdef", "defabc", "apple") )
```

(those that does not contain 'abc') match all three while

```
grep("(abc)",c("abcdef", "defabc", "apple") )
```

behaves correctly and match only the first two. Am I missing something

How can we do that in R ? Also, how can we put hypen together in the list of accepted characters ?

Comment: Show what you’ve tried so far

Comment: consider sticking with white-listing the acceptedcharacters, instead of black-listing the undesired characters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559621/blacklisting-vs-whitelisting-in-forms-input-filtering-and-validation

Comment: If I understand, you want to manually inspect everything that includes a character not in the accepted list?  Seems like you could just use "grep" with a regex of the acceptable characters preceded by a "^" to get matches with characters outside the accepted list

Comment: That is what I would like to do, since the blacklist is unknown. However the 'match anything other than whitelist' evades me. Perhaps I do not understand the 'not contains' logic correctly. _grep("[^abc]",c("abcdef", "defabc", "apple") )_ (all that does not contain 'abc') does not give what I want

Comment: Could you edit the question with a minimal, complete, verifiable example?  Some sample inputs with desired outputs would be helpful in constructing an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to match `a-zA-Z` or `A-z` (because this will match other characters according to the ASCII table). Also, when you specify `àéèçè` do you want all French diacritics to be matched `àâæçéèêëîïôœùûüÿ`?

Comment: @ctwheels I do want to match all French diacritics as you mentioned. The overall idea is I would want those outside the whitelist to be exposed. The whitelist I can fine-tune and add later.

Answer (score 3):

If by "expose the invalid characters" you mean delete the "accepted" ones, then a regex character class should be helpful. From the ?regex help page we can see that a hyphen is already part of the punctuation character vector;

```
[:punct:]
Punctuation characters:
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

So the code could be:

```
x <- 'Ã this Øs an apple'
gsub("[A-z1-9[:punct:] àéèçè]+", "", x)

#[1] "ÃØ"
```

Note that regex has a predefined, locale-specific `"[:alpha:]"` named character class that would probably be both safer and more compact than the expression "[A-zàéèçè]" especially since the post from ctwheels suggests that you missed a few. The ?regex page indicates that "[0-9A-Za-z]" might be both locale- and encoding-specific.

If by "expose" you instead meant "identify the postion within the string" then you could use the negation operator "^" within the character class formalism and apply `gregexpr`:

```
gregexpr("[^A-z1-9[:punct:] àéèçè]+",  x)
[[1]]
[1] 1 8
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[a-z1-9[:punct:] àâæçéèêëîïôœùûüÿ-]+
```

The above regex matches any of the following (one or more times). Note that the parameter `ignore.case=T` used in the code below allows the following to also match uppercase variants of the letters.

- `a-z` Any lowercase ASCII letter
- `1-9` Any digit in the range from 1 to 9 (excludes 0)
- `[:punct:]` Any punctuation character
- The space character
- `àâæçéèêëîïôœùûüÿ` Any valid French character with a diacritic mark
- `-` The hyphen character

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##HYy9CsIwHAd3n@JPphYbQTeLvkW30iHGUAulhiSF4uojuDiKg5@gi4soOPzwuWIr3G3HGe8bmnCSAUsWhaUWUdGI60JJRdjxUnApjFM0V9Yq41hEDGtyXYztvxZal4qFvdzWs4Clgq@GfJzGuq6ki7N2gj0OOOKMEy644oY7Ht8NnnjhjQ/P@t20tYmoyKulUQMprJomofc/)

```
x <- c("This is an 2-piece à-la-carte dessert", "Ã this Øs an apple")
gsub("[a-z1-9[:punct:] àâæçéèêëîïôœùûüÿ-]+", "", x, ignore.case=T)
```

The code above replaces all valid characters with nothing. The result is all invalid characters that exist in the string. The following is the output:

```
[1] ""   "ÃØ"
```